# jquery abort all previous ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, history, pushstate, abort

I tried to abort all the previous ajax request made to load a page.
However I have some difficulties to make it work.

I use jquery ajaxify to ajaxify my website (https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify). But this script didn't abort previous ajax requests. If I quickly  load several page I can see all the previous page content appended then re-appended....And sometimes the  appended data are not the last...

Here the script :

```
(function(window,undefined){

    $(function(){

        var xhr = null;

        $.fn.ajaxify = function(){
                // Prepare
            var $this = $(this);
                // Ajaxify
            $this.find('a').click(function(event){
                // Prepare
                var $this = $(this),
                    url = $this.attr('href'),
                    title = $this.attr('title')||null;

                History.pushState(null,title,url);
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            return $this;
        }

        $body.ajaxify();

        $window.bind('statechange',function(){
                // Prepare Variables
            var State = History.getState(),
                url = State.url,
                relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');

            if (xhr) {
                xhr.abort();
            }

            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(data) {/*append data*/},
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    document.location.href = url;
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });

    });


})(window);
```

Edit: When I abort, the entire site reload the page without ajax. I need to only load the last link click and abort all previous necessaries ajax requests in order to preserve ajax functionnality.

How can I abort this statechange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when we do Abort on Ajax... it triggers the error with textStatus=abort. In your case you are changing location.href hence causing a reload. You can verify it by alert or console.log the textStatus

Solution: In your error handler make sure the textStatus is not abort.

```
 xhr = $.ajax({
         url: url,
         beforeSend: function() {},
         success: function(data) {/*append data*/},
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // aborting actually triggers error with textstatus=abort            
            if (textStatus != "abort") { 
               document.location.href = url;
               return false;
            }
         }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not that. It was just a mistake when I rewrite the script in my question...

Comment: I see... I have updated my answer. This have happened to us and I know exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks a lot! It solves so many problems and js script bugs!